# i have a comma separated list of email ids in a column in python. I want to extract unique list of domain names (sorted) in a new column

Tags: python

I have a column in a python data frame with comma separated list of email ids. I want to extract unique list of domain names, sorted in alphabetical order.

| Email Ids | Required Output |
| --- | --- |
| jgj@myu.com | myu.com |
| abc@gmail.com, lll@yyy.com,xyz@svc.com,abc@yyy.com | gmail.com, svc.com, yyy.com |
| zya@try.com,abs@cba.com | cba.com, try.com |

I tried the following code, however its returning the output of first row for all rows

```
def Dom1(lpo):
    mylist1 = []
    for i in lpo:
        domain = str(i).split("@")[1]
        domain1=domain.replace('>','')
        domain1=domain1.replace(']'," ")
        if domain1 not in mylist1:
            mylist1.append(domain1)
            mylist1=sorted(mylist1, key=str.lower)
        return mylist1

df['Email_Id1']=df.apply(lambda row: Dom1(df['Email_Id']),axis=1)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: is the column  `Email_Id` a string or an array of emails ? Can you also share how you are initializing this dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the column `Email_Id` is a list of email ids.

Here is how your dataframe should look. All the values should be a list even if it has only 1 item. I have a feeling that a single email is not being stored as a list of strings and this is probably your source of error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Email_Id': [['jgj@myu.com'], ['abc@gmail.com', 'lll@yyy.com', 'xyz@svc.com,abc@yyy.com'], ['zya@try.com','abs@cba.com']] })
df
```

##### Initial Dataframe

[image: Dataframe]

And then with a few minor changes and cleanup here is how you can apply the lambda function.

- Apply it to only a series instead of the whole dataframe.
- Also I am not sure why you are calling
  `domain1=domain.replace('>','')` and `domain1=domain1.replace(']'," ")` domain names should not have such characters.
- You don't need to sort after every insertion. Just sort it while returning the list as it will be called only once.
- Change your variable names so that they make sense.
- You could use a python set, but if you do not have a lot of emails in a single row, a list should do just fine

```
def get_domain(emails):
    domains = []
    for email in emails:
        d = str(email).split("@")[1]
        if d not in domains:
            domains.append(d)

    return sorted(domains, key=str.lower)

df['Email_Id1'] = df['Email_Id'].apply(lambda x: get_domain(x))
df
```

##### Final Dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do a one-liner here:

```
df["domains"]=df["emails"].apply(lambda row: [ email[email.find("@")+1:] for email in row]).apply(sorted)
```

Comment: This solution worked great once. However when i rerun it i am getting the following error -  'float' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

col1 = ['jgj@myu.com', 'abc@gmail.com, lll@yyy.com,xyz@svc.com,abc@yyy.com', 'zya@try.com,abs@cba.com']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Email Ids':col1})

def getUniqueEmail(st1):
    result_obj = {}
    for i in st1.split(','):
        if i not in result_obj:
            result_obj[re.sub('^.+@','', i)] = 1
    return ','.join(sorted(list(result_obj.keys()), key=str.lower))

df1['Required output'] = df1['Email Ids'].apply(lambda x: getUniqueEmail(x))
```